# Refreshing <p> tag using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, sql, refresh, paragraph

I have a script that updates SQL in a database and changes the value of whatever is in a certain paragraph. This however only does it on refresh and so I would like the value to change after clicking the button that executes the script. I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
 var url = 'index.phtml';          
        $(".like").load(url + " .like");
```

Comment: Does the script you call return anything? How are you calling it? It would be easier for the script that changes the value to return the value to the caller so that you can replace it, rather than downloading the entire page.

Comment: An html snippet would be helpful here as well. (At minimum what the paragraph tag you're using looks like) One thing I can say for sure it's that the url you've constructed looks malformed: "index.phtml .like".

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in button event:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
   var url = 'index.phtml';          
        $(".like").load(url + " .like");
});
```

And you can manipulate the url variable by declaring it outside the event and set it based on your logic if you want.